# Missing the 2 and 3 in Prime

Tags: java

I am missing the prime numbers, 2 and 3 from the output.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> findPrimes(int n){

    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){

        for(int x = i - 1; x > 2; x--)

            if(i % x == 0)
                break;
            else if(x == 3 && i != 4)
                primes.add(i);
        }
    return primes;
}
```

When I put `n = 72`, it prints good, but 2 and 3 are not being output. I have no clue why it keeps printing that. Any help would be great. As shown below.

Output:

```
Prime numbers: 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71
```

Thanks! If you have another way, feel free to throw out, something I can learn from. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Your code explains the problem. The second for loop will terminate before it's executed even once due to the conditional always being false for values 3 and below.

First loop run: i = 2, x = 1, 1 is not more than 2, so the loop does not run.
Second run: i = 3, x = 2, 2 is not more than 2, so once again, same priblem.

Answer (score 4):

When i=2 or i=3, x would initialise to 1 or 2, hence it will never enter the nested for loop (because x>2 is not fulfilled), thus `primes.add(i)` will not get executed.

Hint: A better way to print prime numbers 2...N is to use sieve approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 4):

Edit: After re-evaluation, I've realized your logic is a bit off throughout. The code should actually read:

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){

    for(int x = 2; x <= i; x++)

        if(i == x)
            primes.add(i);
        else if(i % x == 0)
            break;
}
```

After testing this, it appears to work correctly.

Comment: Interesting... So, I will have to replace 2 with something else?

Comment: Yes, see above, you'll want to replace `2` with `0`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. However, it still prints out the same output.

Comment: I updated my answer, it appears your logic wasn't quite right for finding prime numbers. Please let me know if this works, I am not able to test it myself currently.

Answer (score 0):

When i = 2 or 3, x is < 2 and the inner for loop doesn't execute.

I'd change x to count up from 2:

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
    for(int x = 2; x <= i; x++)
        if( x == i)
          primes.add(i);
        else if (i % x == 0)
          break;
    }
return primes;
```

}

Typing this out on an iphone is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Inner for loop won't execute values less than 2. So, you have to initialize  x =2; in inner for loop.

for(int x = 2; x <= i; x++)

Try this.